# Azure App Service Intermittent Endpoint Connection Failure via RestSharp

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, restsharp, azure-webjobs, digest-authentication

I seeking your input, if not, help in solving this issue which has creeped up recently.

I have an `Azure App Service` running on `Windows`+`.NET Core 5` which also houses a few WebJobs. These Webjobs do some processes for such it uses `RestSharp` ver. 106 to an endpoint service that uses `Digest Authentication`.

Quite recently onwards, I am finding that most of Webjobs are returning the following Error:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
> properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
> failed because connected host failed to respond.

I am clueless as to where to begin. Some previous posts cited that the reason to get such errors is limitations in the Host Server (Which apparently is a third-party source). I have consulted the Third Party source, and they confirmed that there aren't any limitations placed at their end and all of their services are working fine.

I am unaware if there is any limitations for Outward calls in Azure App Service.

I have placed retries, but it proves to be 50-50.

Comment: NAT port exhaustion? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-intermittent-outbound-connection-errors Off-topic, but I hope you are aware that .NET5 is out of support, right? https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core

Comment: That makes sense. Thank You. However, the stats in `App Service > Diagnose and Solve Problem > SNAT*` don't say any issue. But seems the cause as I could execute from Local terminal without any issue.